# Rails - undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class in new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actioncontroller

I can't get why, but my new view started to crash.

I have model Ticket

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :body, :department, :email, :name, :reference, :subject, :status
 has_many :replies, :dependent => :destroy
```

and simple new action

```
def new
  logger.debug "#{@ticket}"
  @ticket = Ticket.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @ticket }
  end
end
```

and new.haml.html(**sorry for wrong haml formatting**):

```
 = form_for @ticket do |f|
 - if @ticket.errors.any?
 #error_explanation
  %h2= "#{pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this ticket from being saved:"
  %ul
    - @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li= msg

 .field
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
 .field
 - if current_admin
 = f.label :email
 = f.text_field :email, :value => "#{current_admin.email}", :disabled => :true
 - else
  = f.label :email
 = f.text_field :email
 .field
 = f.label :department
 = f.select :department, options_for_select(["First department","Second department","Third department"])
.field
 = f.label :subject
 = f.text_field :subject
 .field
  = f.label :body
 = f.text_area :body
- if current_admin
 .field
  = f.label :status
    = f.select :status, options_for_select(["Waiting for Staff Response","Waiting for Customer","On Hold", "Cancelled", "Completed"])
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
1: = form_for @ticket do |f|
2:   - if @ticket.errors.any?
3:     #error_explanation
4:       %h2= "#{pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this ticket from being saved:"
app/views/tickets/_form.html.haml:1:in   
`_app_views_tickets__form_html_haml__659380982_96991070'
 Rendered /home/denmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib
/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.9ms)
 Rendered /home/denmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib
 /action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.1ms)
Rendered /home/denmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib
/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (42.2ms)
```

and routes.rb

```
 resources :tickets do 
  resources :comments
 end
```

I can create Ticket from console, so where is problem ? Can someone suggest where are errors ?

Comment: can you post the first lines of the stack trace ?

Comment: that's weird. how do you render the _form partial ? sometimes the variables are not available in the partials, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: I created new empty project as in previous(render 'form') and it is working. The porblem, that I need my old project. I tried to copy code from partial, but it doesn't work. What I need to do ? Work in new projec? But it is running from problem.

Comment: do you use `render partial: 'form'` in your `new.html.erb` ?

Comment: I will try. It is twice strange, because it worked, and then stopped working.

Comment: can you be more specific ? it's hard to help with such (non-)informations. what errors do you get ?

Comment: When I copy code from partial or use your variant it gives me the same error `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class`. What else info do you need ?

Comment: hmmm... what did you change when it started to fail ?

Comment: I changed database and everything started to fall

Comment: stupid question, but do your `tickets` table still exist ?

Comment: Of course, because I can create them from console

Comment: sorry dude, i'm out of ideas now

Comment: How is "view.haml.html" being rendered? You've shown the action `new`, which will render the view `new.haml.html`, *not* the view you've listed. Show us the actual action that is being invoked, if any.

Comment: @meagar, I posted controller, posted code from 'form' partial, what I call from new.haml.html. What else do you need ?

Comment: You posted `view.haml.html`, which is *not* being invoked by the action you posted. Somewhere between the action and that view, `@ticket` is becoming null.

Comment: Sorry, for this stupid error.,it is invoked. It is new.haml.html)

Comment: If you are totally out of ideas try `form_for :ticket ...` instead.

Comment: @244an, it seems to be name conflict. I can't get it, but when I started to recreating project without old routes and views - everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@ticket` somehow gets "nilified". Thats because when you look inside of form_for

```
 def form_for(record, options = {}, &proc)
   # .... 
   object = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
   object_name = options[:as] || ActiveModel::Naming.param_key(object)
   # ....
end
```

where `ActiveModel::Naming.param_key(object)` gets called we end up in the following method

```
  def model_name_from_record_or_class(record_or_class)
    (record_or_class.is_a?(Class) ? record_or_class : record_or_class.class).model_name
  end
```

There you can see if you pass nil into this method it will throw the error you posted - so check where and why @ticket gets `nil`
To do that you might want to follow [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html), it explains how to debug a rails app.

---

And you might also want to swap those lines.

```
def new
    logger.debug "#{@ticket}"
    @ticket = Ticket.new
end
```

Because the way its is right now you wont get any useful output.

Comment: How can I track this ? Maybe it will be faster to recreate project, because I need to show project tomorrow.

Comment: @m_x, something in my routes or views naming.

Comment: to track where `@ticket` becomes `nil` use the debugger

Comment: as long as you go to `localhost:3000/ticket/new` there is no need to dig through the routes and your naming is totally ok